# pairing students into groups

Tags: probability

If we want to assign students into groups of 3, how many ways are there to choose the groups in which the order doesn’t matter.

My answer:

•   Number of ways of choosing “one” group of 3:
= (n!)/((n-3)! . 3!)
•   Number of ways of choosing all groups is what I still can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $n$ is a multiple of $3$, else it is not possible to divide $n$ students into groups of $3$.

Have the students form one line. Let students 1,2,3 be in group 1, students 4,5,6, be in group 2, etc.

There are $n!$ ways the students can line up. However this overcounts the number of groupings since there are $\tfrac{n}{3}!$ ways to reorder the group numbers, and $3! $ ways for the students to reorder themselves in the same group (for each group).

Thus, the total number of groupings is $\dfrac{n!}{\tfrac{n}{3}! \cdot (3!)^{n/3}}$.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy, makes sense.

Comment: You can multiply that by $\begin{pmatrix}n\\ 3\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor\end{pmatrix}$ to generalize it for all $n$ (the number of ways to choose the kids to put in groups).